# 2006 Chevy Cobalt AC pulley seized?

Tags: chevrolet, ac, cobalt, serpentine-belt, air-compressor

In my 2006 Chevy Cobalt 2.2liter Ecotech, the serpentine belt broke. I went out and bought a new one and didn't check the pulleys prior to putting the new one on. I haven't changed the belt before and just assumed it finally failed.

After installing the new one, turning on the car caused the car to stall after a few secs.  I turned the car on again and keep the engine RPMs up to keep it running to inspect the belt and noticed the belt had a little wobble in it and it started to smoke around the AC Pulley.

Does it sound like it is a seized up pulley and if so, what are some solutions to fix it.   I am having the hardest time finding anything outside of just changing the whole compressor to get the car back up and running.

Thank you for any help/insight you can give.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Since your AC compressor has a clutch, even if the clutch has seized up, the compressore should still be able to go around. It sounds like to me the entire compressor has seized and therefore I'd bet it will need replaced.

Comment: Can you rotate the clutch hub (the front part of the compressor pulley) with your hands (engine off and key in pocket obv)? If it's rotating (it should be a smooth rotation with uniform resistance on one whole turn), only the pulley bearing is at fault. If it's not rotating, the entire compressor has seized and it could have taken the pulley bearing with it. Either way, if the pulley bearing is shot unplugging the clutch coil terminal won't be a solution, the bearing has to be replaced. If it's healthy, unplugging the coil terminal is enough. Do that check, and let us know.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the replies. I do not have to tools/jack needed to manually check the pulley system as you said @Al_ but I did do a little check myself.

Comment: I went out and turned the key over to power the car up and turned the AC button off. By doing this i was thinking it would deactivate the clutch and let the pulley be standalone.

Comment: I turned the car on and listened to it and had no drops in RPMs.  As soon as i turned the AC on it goes to stall like before. So i turned off the AC again and things went back to normal. I went out and opened the hood to check the pulley/belt system and everything seems okay except the (ac)pulley does make a little noise.  It does sound like the bearing is on its last leg. I let the car ideal for 20mins with no problems. Reving it up to about 2k RPMs at random intervals without any issues (outside of bearing sounding a little bad).

Comment: Do you perchance remember AC not cooling enough right before the problem started? Low refrigerant can kill a compressor by depriving it of lubrication and overheating it. That's what probably damaged the bearing too. On the other hand, a defective pulley bearing (Very rare) can damage the shaft seal on a otherwise healthy compressor. If your compressor seized, you're looking at a shorter belt/junkyard compressor with coil unplugged and no further action if you want to give up on AC, or a system flush with condenser & dryer replacement and new/second hand compressor if you want AC back again.

Comment: If the bearing were still ok you could have pulled the clutch coil terminal and be done with it until you wanted to fix AC. The noisy bearing issue needs to be addressed before the AC pulley bearing seizes up.